# Im encountering syntax error 1064 on my MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, heidisql

Hi rephrasing my question earlier I added the full statement below.codes should retain data from past 7 days.Thank you.

CREATE PROCEDURE `logs_user_aht_delete`(
IN logs_database VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET utf,

IN logs_data_retention_db INT(10) )

BEGIN

SET @v = concat('DELETE FROM `',logs_database,'`.`user_aht` ua WHERE
IFNULL(ua.completed_at, ua.inserted_at) < (CURRENT_DATE - 7)- INTERVAL ',logs_data_retention_db ,' DAY);');

PREPARE stm FROM @v;

EXECUTE stm;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;

END$$

Comment: You aren’t setting delimiters

Comment: It has  i just didn't include it

Comment: My first thought given you did not provide the full error message and you are using heidisql is that you had not set delimiters if that was true then you would get a 1064 error. It's very important that you include the full error message since in this case a 1064 error could occur because you did not set delimiters, the procedure code was syntactically incorrect or the created sql statement is found to be incorrect when submitted Also not including the full error message is a possible deterrent to quick answers

Comment: Thank you this is helpful .I'll gonna edit the question and put the error message as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this select @v in the procedure commenting out the prepare,exec,deallocate and examine the result.

Two thing are syntactically incorrect 1) the table alias where you are part way to a multi-table delete 2) you are providing the days to be deleted as a parameter and also hard coding it in the build of @v

I suggest you change to

```
SET @v = concat('DELETE ua FROM ',logs_database,'.user_aht ua
WHERE IFNULL(ua.completed_at, ua.inserted_at) < (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL ',logs_data_retention_db ,' DAY);');
```

Comment: Hi just a follow up question how to execute it using an sql call statement?? If I wanted to get data from past 7 days??

Comment: call procedurename(parameter1,parameter2); in the order and datatype defined in the create statement.

Comment: Hello would you mind giving me a sample syntax for the call? Thanks.